PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 3): A cacophonic crossword
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
So, the PSE Advent Calendar has only just started, but I have been puzzling non-stop already.
You could say I'm already quite over-puzzled!
And that's not even taking into account this musically-looking crossword puzzle here below.

How on earth am I going to sleep tonight?





I'll name that tune in 14

 SILENT NIGHT meaning that you will "sleep in heavenly peace".

The crossword has

 clues and answers which use SOLFEGE words as additional possible lights.

Here's the solution grid (hopefully my handwriting is legible):

 

The answers are Top-Left to Bottom-Right

 7. S[TI]G 9. [RE][RE]AD 10. A[RE]O[LA] 12. [MI]NGLE = [MI]X 15. FEL[LA] = [LA]D 21. DIS[SOL]VENT = [SOL]U[TI]ON 23. EXHI[LA]RATE = E[LA]TE  24. [DO]RMANT = [LA]TENT  25. PO  27. CHE[MI]CAL [RE]ACTION = [RE][DO]X 28. AUC[TI]ONED OFF = [SOL]D 34. [FA][FA]N[FA][RE]  35. CON[SOL]ATION = [SOL]ACE  36. [TI][RE]D  46. [LA] RAP AR[TI]ST = D[RE]  47. [SOL]AR 49. SO[FA]

Top-Right to Bottom-Left

 2. SE[MI][RE][TI][RE]D  7. SA[LA][MI]  8 [DO] AN IMPRESSION = [MI][MI]C  9. LIE [DO]WN = [RE][LA]X  11. AGO  14. SINGER CUR[RE]NTLY ON THE ROAD [LA]ST NAME = [RE]A  18. ACCUMU[LA][TI]ON = ACC[RE][TI]ON  20. [LA][LA][LA]ND  22. CUR[RE]NCY = RUPEE  26. CONCNTRATED F[LA]VOR ADDER = [MI]O  35. MUSICAL SEC[TI]ON PERFORMED ALONE = [SOL]O  37. SHORT-LIVED T[RE]ND = [FA]D  51. TRADI[TI]ONAL PORTUGESE MUSCI GEN[RE] = [FA][DO]

Bottom-Right to Top-Left

 1. [FA]MOUS MEXICAN BEER = [SOL]  4. [DO]ZE = [RE]ST  5. VOICE ACT[RE]SS [LA]YING MEG FIRST NAME = [MI][LA]  17. PROTEC[TI]ON = CA[RE]  19. [MI]SFORTUNES = CA[LA][MI][TI]ES  31. [MI]ND  32. A[DO][RE]R = AD[MI][RE]R  40. P[RE]POSI[TI]ON = IN  42. FORMU[LA] 1 CIRCUIT = IMO[LA]  43. ICE C[RE]AM BRAND = [SOL]ERO  45. [MI]MOSA  48. 2010 AC[TI]ON MOVIE = [RE]D 52. EX[TI]NCT BIRD = [DO][DO]

Bottom-Left to Top-Right

 3. UL[TI]MATE = [LA]ST  6. [FA][TI]GUE = [TI][RE]  30. I[SOL]DE  31. US [RE]PUBLICAN SENATOR FIRST NAME = [MI]TT  32. A[DO]  33. [RE][TI][RE]D US TENNIS P[LA]YER FIRST NAME = AND[RE]  38. MR  39. LEFT-WING POLI[TI]CAL MOVEMENT = AN[TI][FA]  40. SOUTH KO[RE]AN FEMALE SINGER = I[RE]NE  41. [RE]START COMPUTER = [RE]BOOT  44. AMA  45. CONVERTS SOUND WAVES INTO ELECTRICAL CUR[RE]NT = [MI]C   47. PRESEVE[RE]S = [SOL]DIERS  49. SUSTAINABLE AGRICULTU[RE] [RE]SEARCH AND EDUCA[TI]ON = SA[RE]  50. [DO]OR

Reading off the lights below the grid then gives

 SOL-LA-SOL-MI SOL-LA-SOL-MI RE-RE-TI DO-DO-SOL which is the tune to SILENT NIGHT.

A lovely puzzle, I particularly liked 24. going South-West and 34. going South-East.

Great so far, however: how might the question then be answered, given what you have found so far? (The [knowledge] tag applies here)

@sarsaparilla I have expanded on the initial answer.

Please could you add the filled in grid

@fljx Best endeavours grid now added.
